# Is there any way that I can change the color of only the clicked line in Line Chart (Recharts)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I am having problems with my code regarding line charts. So, I want to click only a certain line to change the color of it but what happens is all the line in the chart changes their stroke color. Here is my code:

```
    export default class LineChartPresentational extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
    isclicked: true, }}

    changeStrokeclick() {
    this.setState({isclicked: !this.state.isclicked} )}

    render() {
       let strokecolor = this.state.isclicked ? "#9da0a5" : "#2d75ed" 
    return ( 
       <div>
         <div id="lclastdataref" style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>
         <span>Last Data Refresh: {linechartdf.date} </span>
      </div>
      <div className='line-charts'>
      <div className="line-chart-wrapper " style={{ width: window.innerWidth / 2, height: window.innerHeight / 2, }}>

        <ResponsiveContainer>
          <LineChart
            width={width} height={height} margin={{ top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20 }} data={linechartdata} id="Line-Chart">
            <XAxis dataKey={xAxisColumn} />
            <YAxis domain={['auto', 'auto']} />
            <Tooltip cursor={false} />
            {
              linechartdata.map((entry, index) => (
                <Line stroke={strokecolor} onClick={this.changeStrokeclick.bind(this)} name={linechartdata[index].dataKey} strokeWidth={lineThickness} dataKey={`value${index + 1}`} dot={false} className={`value${index + 1}`}/>
              ))
            }
            </LineChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
); }
```

Please I really need your help as you can see my lines are created using a loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to change `isclicked` to `clickedLineID` and make it accept string like

```
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
    clickedLineID: '', }}
```

You need to pass the line ID with onClick

```
  <Tooltip cursor={false} />
            {
              linechartdata.map((entry, index) => (
                <Line stroke={strokecolor} onClick={this.changeStrokeclick.bind(this, index)} name={linechartdata[index].dataKey} strokeWidth={lineThickness} dataKey={`value${index + 1}`} dot={false} className={`value${index + 1}`}/>
              ))
            }
            </LineChart>
```

then handle your data that coming from clicked line

```
  changeStrokeclick(data) {
    console.log(data, 'see what is coming');
    this.setState({clickedLineID: data} )
   }
```

So the current clicked line is in `clickedLineID` state

We dont need this code any more, as well I don't prefer to keep it inside `render()`

```
let strokecolor = this.state.isclicked ? "#9da0a5" : "#2d75ed"
```

Change stroke line inside your Tooltip to

```
stroke={index === this.state.clickedLineID ? "#9da0a5" : "#2d75ed"}
```

So finall code will be like this

```
    <Tooltip cursor={false} />
                {
                  linechartdata.map((entry, index) => (
                    <Line stroke={index === this.state.clickedLineID ? "#9da0a5" : "#2d75ed"}
 onClick={this.changeStrokeclick.bind(this, index)} name={linechartdata[index].dataKey} strokeWidth={lineThickness} dataKey={`value${index + 1}`} dot={false} className={`value${index + 1}`}/>
                  ))
                }
                </LineChart>
```

**UPDATE:**

if click again to remove the color just change the `changeColor` to

```
  changeColor = (data) =>{
    console.log(data, 'check what we received from the button')
    if(this.state.clickedItem === data){
      this.setState({clickedItem: null})
    }else{
      this.setState({ clickedItem: data })
    }
  };
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! :) Although when I click it again it doesn't revert back to the original color. :(

Comment: @Liam - looks like your examples were removed from codesandbox